# Triple bar meaning in proof of the Principle of Superposition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation

What does the triple bar mean in this context?

"Thus $y(t)≡0,...$"

[image]

Comment: $y(t)\equiv 0\iff \forall t,\quad y(t)=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that $y(t) = 0$ for all $t$ in the domain. In other words, $y$ is the zero function. Sometimes this will be described as "$y$ is *identically* zero" in the sense of a function identity.